# Detailed explanation of how to add "Twig_Extension_Debug" to Wordpress/Timber

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

I have to add `Twig_Extension_Debug` because I really need this function for debugin.
People have told me that I need to manually add the `Twig_Extension_Debug`. I looked at the explanation in the TWIG Website, however I lack the understanding of where I should add it.
Adding it to the `functions.php` in Wordpress does nothing. Where do I add it?

Comment: Can someone please give me a hint, or help me? :)

Comment: I have to BUMP this thread...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you already look at the [Debugging Guide](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/debugging/)? In Timber, the `Timber_Debug_Extension` is automatically added when you set `WP_DEBUG` to `true` in your **wp-config.php** file. You can then use `{{ dump() }}` in your Twig files.

Comment: I figured out that i had my WP_DEBUG too far down in the wp-config.php. Meaning i had to move it upwards.